# Use writerow to put a list of elements in the same row

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the source code I have. xs is a list of time float numbers, I am trying to put all of the elements of the list to the same row.

```
outFile=open('testing.csv','w',newline='')
writeFile=csv.writer(outFile)
writeFile.writerow(['cell'])
writeFile.writerow(['LevelLine for Impedance Magnitude:',baseline])
writeFile.writerow(['TimeMag (second):',xs])'
```

First I had tried using the for loop to load the numbers such as

```
for i in range(len(xs)-1):
   writeFile.writerow('TimeMag(second):',xs[i])
```

However, the output result of this code prints xs[i] in different rows. I had tried watching the video and checked the CSV writerow function, but I couldn't find anything that put a list of elements to the same row.

I want my output like this:

output: 
row 1: Cell
row 2: TimeMag(second): xs[0] xs[1] xs[2] and so on.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The object you pass to `writerow()` should be a flat iterable containing the items you want to write to the row. Your attempt:

```
writeFile.writerow(['TimeMag (second):',xs])
```

...isn't flat, because it contains two elements, one of which (`xs`) is itself a list. Instead, you basically want to prepend your string (`'TimeMag (second):'`) to the `xs` list. This should do what you're expecting:

```
writeFile.writerow(['TimeMag (second):'] + xs)
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can put it to a specific row? for example, I want to put TimeMag xs to row 6 instead of row 2.

Comment: They'll go to the file in the order you call `writerow()`. If you want to put other rows first, write them first. Alternatively, you can put everything in a big list-of-lists, rearrange that any way you like, then call [`writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows).